# Create pd.DataFrame with specific text format

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

Having a text file "sample.txt" containing key-value pairs as in:

```
{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}   
{'A':0, 'B':5, 'C':6}   
{'A':2, 'B':3, 'C':7}
```

how can I efficiently obtain a pandas dataframe with keys as columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you could get them to a list of dicts, you could just use pd.DataFrame() on it:

```
data_list = \
[{'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3},   
 {'A':0, 'B':5, 'C':6},   
 {'A':2, 'B':3, 'C':7}]

pd.DataFrame(data_list)
```